# OS permissions causing issue with removing files in Pycharm

Tags: python, windows, pycharm, admin

On my company laptop (running Windows 10) I am using PyCharm to develop some scripts where I use the os module to create and delete directories. However, whenever I call a function that deletes old copies of files, I get a permission error:

```
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\\\Users\\\\User\\\\PycharmProjects\\\\Project
```

I've narrowed down the issue to the fact that my company has set permissions that do not allow for anyone else to delete subfolders and files:

[image: Security Settings for a Test folder I created]

I am unable to edit this permission. I am able to add new permissions.

I've tried running PyCharm as an administrator to see if that would allow the python script running in PyCharm to bypass the above settings and delete files, but that seems to have failed.

Is there any way for me to get a python script running in PyCharm to bypass these permissions? I believe if I were to download my entire project and execute the script in Powershell or CMD (being run as admin) that I would be able to do what I want to do, but I'm currently working in a venv and would rather not have to load all of my package dependencies onto my machine.

Comment: `C:\\\\Users\\\\User\\\\PycharmProjects\\\\Project` That's too many backslashes.  How are you constructing this pathname?

Comment: Oh that is just the path that PyCharm spits out in the error logs. The actual path is correct and runs fine. Unsure why the error logs give that output

Comment: It's not a PyCharm thing, but a Windows thing - you're not allowed to just change files in any location and the Users folders are only allowed to be changed by those users themselves or appropriate admins. If there was some way for your script or PyCharm to bypass these restrictions, they would be rather pointless. What is your use case? Why does the script need to change something there - on what authority? Perhaps your script needs to run as a user that has the appropriate rights, if you have some valid reason to change files there.

Comment: @Grismar I am using some webservices to log data from another server, and then I process this data into a number of summary files. Only the most current set of data matters to me, so I was deleting all priorly requested data, and then making the webservice request to create a new set of summary files. I suppose I could try to just overwrite the preexisting data, but then I might be left with some files that not updated and hence useless since they are based on out of date data

Answer (score 0):

My current workaround, while crude, is to change the filepath for each of the files to be the recycling bin. Then when running my script, new files will simply fill the now empty folders. To do this I imported the send2trash module.

```
pip install send2trash

from send2trash import send2trash

send2trash('C:\\path\\to\\your\\file')
```

I haven't tested any commands to empty the recycling bin programatically (I'd be wary to delete the contents there in case something important was placed there by mistake), but for now this somewhat handles what I need. Ideally I would like to be able to delete the specific files.